# Cover a sphere by two closed subsets not containing a closed self-antipodal connected subset?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness

## Question

(Fulton's *Algebraic Topology, A First Course*, **Problem 4.40**) Suppose the sphere $S^2=A\cup B$ where $A,B\subseteq S^2$ are two closed subsets of $S^2$. Is it true that either $A$ or $B$ must contain a closed connected set $X$ such that $X=X^*$, the set of antipoles of points of $X$?

I have no idea on how to proceed. It's an exercise immediately after Borsuk-Ulam theorem. The condition that $X$ is connected is somewhat tough. Otherwise, the existence is a direct (much weaker) result of Borsuk-Ulam.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: This feels like a counterexample: http://654459157.r.lightningbase-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/tennisball.jpg

Comment: Maybe a nice way to see that the tennis ball is a counterexample is to note that each connected component of $A \cap A^\star$ is disjoint from its image under the antipodal map.  And similarly for $B\cap B^\star$.  $X$ would have to be contained in $A \cap A^\star$ or $B\cap B^\star$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wspin's counterexample:

Identify the sphere with the inscribed cube and let $A$ be the front, bottom, and back faces. Let $B$ be the top, left, and right faces.  Then each connected component of $A\cap A^\star$ is disjoint from its image under the antipodal map, and similarly for $B \cap B^\star$. Assume $X \subset A$. Then $X\subset A\cap A^\star$, so that $X$ is contained in one the connected components, a contradiction since $X^\star =X$.  Similarly $X$ cannot be contained in $B$.